# Installing PyLucene 3.0.3 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: java, python, lucene, makefile, pylucene

I'm attempting to install PyLucene 3.0.3 on Ubuntu 10.04. This has proven considerably challenging, but so far I've:

- Patched setuptools to allow building of JCC, as instructed in the PyLucene docs.
- Built JCC via: cd pylucene-3.0.3-1/jcc; python setup.py build
- Built Lucene 3.0.3 via ant, and installed the jar to /usr/share/java/lucene-core-3.0.3-dev.jar. Note, I have Ubuntu's default Lucene package installed to /usr/share/java/lucene-core-2.9.2.jar which also symlinks to /usr/share/java/lucene-core.jar

I'm now trying to "make" PyLucene, but I get the error:

```
cd lucene-java-3.0.3;  -Dversion=3.0.3
/bin/sh: -Dversion=3.0.3: not found
make: *** [lucene-java-3.0.3/build/lucene-core-3.0.3.jar] Error 127
```

The file pylucene-3.0.3-1/doc/documentation/install.html makes mention to "edit Makefile to match your environment", but I'm not sure what that means. The makefile seems to contain the same Lucene version number as the one I installed. How else do I need to edit my makefile in order to build PyLucene?

Edit: After uncommenting a section in the makefile (thanks Torsten) for compiling under Ubuntu 8.10 (seriously, 8.10?!) most of it seemed to compile fine, but I still received an error. Several components reported "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" but the final build ended with:

```
/usr/bin/python -m jcc --shared --jar lucene-java-3.0.3/build/lucene-core-3.0.3.jar --jar lucene-java-3.0.3/build/contrib/snowball/lucene-snowball-3.0.3.jar --jar lucene-java-3.0.3/build/contrib/analyzers/common/lucene-analyzers-3.0.3.jar --jar lucene-java-3.0.3/build/contrib/regex/lucene-regex-3.0.3.jar --jar lucene-java-3.0.3/build/contrib/memory/lucene-memory-3.0.3.jar --jar lucene-java-3.0.3/build/contrib/highlighter/lucene-highlighter-3.0.3.jar --jar lucene-java-3.0.3/build/contrib/queries/lucene-queries-3.0.3.jar --jar build/jar/extensions.jar  --package java.lang java.lang.System java.lang.Runtime --package java.util java.util.Arrays java.text.SimpleDateFormat java.text.DecimalFormat java.text.Collator --package java.io java.io.StringReader java.io.InputStreamReader java.io.FileInputStream --exclude org.apache.lucene.queryParser.Token --exclude org.apache.lucene.queryParser.TokenMgrError --exclude org.apache.lucene.queryParser.QueryParserTokenManager --exclude org.apache.lucene.queryParser.ParseException --exclude org.apache.lucene.search.regex.JakartaRegexpCapabilities --exclude org.apache.regexp.RegexpTunnel --python lucene --mapping org.apache.lucene.document.Document 'get:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;' --mapping java.util.Properties 'getProperty:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;' --rename org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.SpanScorer=HighlighterSpanScorer --version 3.0.3 --module python/collections.py --files 200 --build 
/usr/bin/python: jcc is a package and cannot be directly executed
make: *** [compile] Error 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did this before (but without installing Lucene's default package in Ubuntu). I don't know what exactly is `Error 127`, but in my case it helped to set `NUM_FILES=200` from the original `NUM_FILES=2` in my Makefile. For some reason when `NUM_FILES=2` it creates really huge files in memory which ubuntu will not handle. With `NUM_FILES=200` the chunks are smaller and installation worked for me in the end. For python 2.6 you also have to change the `JCC` setting in Makefile (see below).

Here the part which was important for me in the Makefile:

```
# Linux     (Ubuntu 8.10 64-bit, Python 2.5.2, OpenJDK 1.6, setuptools 0.6c9)
PREFIX_PYTHON=/usr
ANT=ant
PYTHON=$(PREFIX_PYTHON)/bin/python
JCC=$(PYTHON) -m jcc.__main__ --shared
NUM_FILES=200
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you had added `__main__`. That compiled perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Installing PyLucene should be really easier. I always spend half a day for it. :/